# DataStax OpsCenter ignoring proxy environment variable

Tags: proxy, opscenter

we installed DataStax OpsCenter (v4.1.1) on a Debian 7.4 server.
After starting the service, the following error is logged in /var/log/opscenter/opscenterd.log:

ERROR: Trying to download https://opscenter.datastax.com:443/definitions/4.1.1/version.md5 resulted in following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/Definitions.py", line 103, in getNewHash
        ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.

As we have to use a proxy (squid), we configured the variables in /etc/environment.
Unfortunately, OpsCenter is not using these environment variables.
A manual download of this file via proxy is working fine.

Is there any possibility to configure a proxy for OpsCenter or any other workaround?
Many thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: What environment variable is defined in /etc/environment that would allow opscenterd to talk to the internet (eg, opscenter.datastax.com)?  You can certainly change /usr/share/opscenter/bin/opscenter to include /etc/environment as a workaround

Comment: I defined proxy variables (http_proxy, HTTP_PROXY,https_proxy,HTTPS_PROXY) in /etc/environment.

Comment: Does patching bin/opscenter work as a workaround?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how/where to include the environment file within the file bin/opscenter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit the file /etc/datastax-agent/datastax-agent-env.sh and append the follow line:

   `JVM_OPTS="-Dhttps.proxyPort=<PROXY_PORT> -Dhttp.proxyHost=<PROXY> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<PROXY> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<PROXY_PORT>`
2. Restart the Agent
   /etc/init.d/datastax-agent restart